# Difficulty Understanding the Last Step of Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning

I'm having a tough time understanding the last "step" of Principal Component Analysis. Specifically, I'm trying to understand the following.

$$Z^* = ZP^*$$

In the step above, you take the standardized form, $Z$, of your original data and multiply it by $P^*$ where the columns of $P^*$ are the eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_k $ of the covariance matrix arranged from largest corresponding eigenvalue to smallest.

Specifically, I'm having difficulty intuitively understanding how taking a row $z_i$ (or vector of input data) from $Z$ and multiplying it by the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix give you a new vector $z_i^*$ with values that correspond to the "weights" in the direction of each eigenvector.

Comment: Note that the set $\{v_j\}$ is orthothogonal since they are eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix. Since the data is the rows of $Z,$ we have $(z^*_i)_j = (ZP)_{ij} = z_i \cdot v_j$. This should remind you of the notion of weights in a basis - let $\{e_u\}$ be any orthogonal basis. You can write $z = \sum_{u = 1}^m (z\cdot e_u) e_u,$ where $(z \cdot e_u)$ is the weight (or the length of the projection of) $z$ in the direction $e_u$. You're doing the same here, (except that usually in PCA one drops the low eigenvalue vectors, so the $\{v_j\}$ need not from a full basis.)

Comment: Thanks for the help @stochasticboy321, just one question: wouldn't $z = \sum_{u = 1}^{m}(z \cdot e_u)e_u$ only be possible if $e_u$ are orthonormal eigenvectors, not if they are orthogonal? If $e_u$ are orthogonal but not orthonormal, wouldn't it be $z = \sum_{u = 1}^{m}\frac{(z \cdot e_u)}{\|e_u\|^2}e_u$ instead?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, you're quite right. So, assuming that you're working with normalised eigenvectors (which is a standard assumption to make), the above should make sense.